# Drone drifts to same direction even after leaving stick

Tags: transmitter, receiver

I have micro fpv racing drone with jhemcu f4 noxe v3 flight controller. Drone works fine with all functions. But when I try to move drone to any one direction and leaves stick, drone continues moving and don't stop.

Answer (score 2):

The accelerometers need calibrating. If it runs Betaflight, this is a button on the [setup tab](https://betaflight.com/docs/wiki/configurator/setup-tab). You place the drone on a level surface and try to avoid any movement or vibration while the calibration process runs (it only takes a few seconds).

If it still drifts after calibration, your surface isn't quite level. If it drifts left, level the quad with a few thicknesses of paper under the left side and recalibrate.

If it's not running Betaflight, the instructions should tell you how to calibrate it.